# Webapplication stops running code after calling function from another file

Tags: php, curl

My web app stops when it tries executing a function from another file. I am using a `include_once` to include the file where the function is. I am also pretty sure that the path is correct. (if there is anyway to check let me know). the functions which I am trying to use are written in the class.connections.php . Also as you can see I am echoing 2 test. Only the first one shows.

Invite.php

```
global $page_array ;
global $current_user ;

include_once(DITC_PATH."/class.friends.php");
include_once(DITC_PATH."/class.connections.php");

$process_status = $current_user->process_hotmail_contacts ;

global $page_array ;

if($page_array['url']['3'] == 'hotmail'){
    $process_source = 'hotmail' ;
};

if($_GET['code']){

    echo "Test 1 - ";

    $access_token_json = get_hotmail_access_token();

    echo "Test 2 - ";

    if($access_token_json){

        echo 'test';

        update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'hotmail_access_token', $access_token_json);

        $taskurl = "/tasks";

        $data = array();
        $data['type'] = 'process_hotmail_contacts';
        $data['lang'] = get_site_language();
        $data['access_token'] = $access_token_json ;
        $data['user_id'] = $current_user->ID ;

        $options = array();

        add_task($taskurl, $data, $options);

        $process_status = 'busy' ;
        $process_source = 'hotmail' ;
    };
}

$ditc_title = _t("Invite connections") ;
get_header();
```

function in class.connections

```
function get_hotmail_access_token(){

   global $hotmail_creds;

   $fields=array(
      'code'=>  urlencode($hotmail_creds['auth_code']),
      'client_id'=>  urlencode($hotmail_creds['client_id']),
      'client_secret'=>  urlencode($hotmail_creds['client_secret']),
      'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($hotmail_creds['redirect_uri']),
      'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
   );

   $post = '';

   foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
   $post = rtrim($post,'&');
   $curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,'https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf');
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,5);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);

   $response =  json_decode($result);
   $access_token_json = $response->access_token;

   return $access_token_json;

};
```